# autofac configuration for multiple project solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autofac

**Hi guys, I have just Configurated Autofac for  my project, and it works just fine, however...**

The problem occurs when I add a second project to my solution and try to use my configuration there.

this is what I do:

Core project:

1. I configure Autofac to register for Injection all classes that inherit from an interface;
2. Then I Call the method in global.asax file:

   ```
   var autofacBotstrap = new AutofacBootstrap();
   autofacBotstrap.Configure();
   ```

Everything works fine;

But it stops working when I try to call the same method in an other project from the same solution and get this infamous error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object

I found out that it is easy to fix in web api by using GlobalDependencyResolver

**My quetion is: How to fix this for mvc(5)?**

and these are some subquestions:

Which project should be the startup project?
Is something wrong in IIS? Which project should be added to IIS?

I cant find any information on the web, i hope it is becouse of the problem is so simple nobody ever had it. Please Help, I'm loosing hair already!

Comment: What do you mean by: "But it stops working when I try to call the same method in an other project". What method? How are you calling it?

Comment: I think you need to show a code example of this working in your web project, and how you are calling the other project and get the error.